# CSV in Python, doesn't save duplicate data

Tags: python, csv

I have a problem with saving data in csv with python.
Here the code:

```
self.INPUT = [1,2,3,4,5]
self.InLab = {'car':'€','dog':'€','cat':'€','cat':'€','total':'€'}
with open('Input-Output/INPUT.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    inp = []
    for i,j,k in zip(self.INPUT,self.InLab.keys(),self.InLab.values()):
        inp.append(writer.writerow([j, i, k]))
```

My problem is, when I save the given list and the given dictionary in the csv, it saves only the next:

```
car,1,€
dog,2,€
cat,3,€
total,4,€
```

And I expect the following:

```
car,1,€
dog,2,€
cat,3,€
cat,4,€
total,5,€
```

Why the second "cat" isn't taked into account and how can I solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: `InLab` is a dictionary ... it cant contain duplicate `key`. you created with 2 cats as `key`

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. If you forget about writing `csv` and just look at the contents of the dictionary, you'll see where the problem is.

Comment: `dict` is probably the wrong data structure for what you're trying to achieve. A `list` of `tuple` pairs would work: `[('car', '€'), ('dog', '€') ,('cat', '€'), ('cat', '€'), ('total', '€')]`

Comment: @Naveen I get it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't repeat keys in dictionaries.

You can acheive something similar to what you're trying to do with a list of tuples. So, for example:

```
self.INPUT = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
self.InLab = [('car','€'),('dog','€'),('cat','€'),('cat','€'),('total','€')]
with open('Input-Output/INPUT.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    inp = []
    for i, (j, k) in zip(self.INPUT, self.InLab):
        inp.append(writer.writerow([j, i, k]))
```

Comment: @PeterWood Didn't know you could do that! Python is great.

Answer (score 0):

**Write a better question**

Your example code should run out of the box for anyone to reproduce. It also doesn't need to be this complicated.

**Dictionary**

You define `InLab` as `{'car':'€','dog':'€','cat':'€','cat':'€','total':'€'}` but if you were to print it into the console you could see that the actual value assigned is: `{'car': '€', 'dog': '€', 'cat': '€', 'total': '€'}`. This is because a dictionary can't contain duplicate keys.